# Jfrog Artifactory - Unable to do build project due 401 error

Tags: build, artifactory, unauthorized

I’m trying to build a project and it  throws a Artifactory Unauthorized error . I seem to have the same settings.xml as the rest of the team with my Jfrog Artifactory username/password in it.

Would anyone know how to get this resolved

I’m expecting to be able to build the project when I do a gradle clean build from cmd or IntelliJ

Comment: Maybe the client is not challenged for authentication in this repo, can you check on Artifactory side if force authentication is enabled? 
Otherwise, it might be an issue with permissions or credentials.